# Heroku rails 5 app: https load css and javascript normally, but http doesn't receive any css and javascript

Tags: http, heroku, https, ruby-on-rails-5

My rails 5 app on heroku has a problem: https load css and javascript normally, but http doesn't receive any css and javascript. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

Comment: Is there another way? Because I would like to use http://myapp.herrokuapp.com domain, not `https://myapp.herokuapp.com`

Comment: Ok I use absolute path for all assets link with scheme https, now everything is ok.